# I want to merge parts of two notepad files into one file

Tags: python, text, notepad++, text-processing

I have two text files named BOOK1.txt and BOOK2.txt

BOOK1.txt

```html
\id BookName
\ide Encoding
\rem Copyright Information
\h Header
\toc1 Topic1
\toc2 Topic2
\mt1 BookNameEng
\mt1 BookNameHin
\c 1
\p
\v 1 This is first sentence 
\v 2 This is second sentence 
.......... (1000+ sentences)
```

BOOK2.txt

```html
\id BookName
\mt1 BookNameHin
\c 1
\p
\v 1 This is first sentence in Book2
\v 2 This is second sentence in Book2
.......... (1000+ sentences)
```

I want to combine parts of both files, i.e from line 1 to 8 from BOOK1.txt to be merged to line 3 of BOOK2.txt to make BOOK3.txt

BOOK3.txt should look like :

```html
\id BookName
\ide Encoding
\rem Copyright Information
\h Header
\toc1 Topic1
\toc2 Topic2
\mt1 BookNameEng
\mt1 BookNameHin
\c 1
\p
\v 1 This is first sentence in Book2
\v 2 This is second sentence in Book2
.......... (1000+ sentences)
```

Please help. I have 5808 files for processing. That too 66 files each in 44 different languages (same language family). I have 2904 files with header information (line 1 to 8) with old text which I would like to replace with the text in another 2904 files with no header. This is the scenario. I know copy paste is not an easy solution for bulk file processing. If there is any other way out please let me know. I am here to learn from the community. *(this last paragraph added later so as to give more clarity to my question.)*

Comment: Output is not clear, I have given an answer. Check if it satisfies what you need.

Comment: Voting to close because this is in no way programming related. Other than use of a *python* tag, there is no code, no description of code, no problem related to code, no effort to solve the problem using code, and no clear question related to code being asked. Also, see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: For notepad++, copy and paste

Comment: What is a "notepad file"?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write a program for this at all. The easiest method *by far* is to simply open three Notepad windows with BOOK1.txt, BOOK2.txt, and a new window for the output. Copy and paste as needed from the two original files into the output file, and when done, save it as BOOK3.txt.

In fact, it looks like you've already done this, so simply save the text in your question as BOOK3.txt.

I'm not being sarcastic! This is the best way to solve your problem.

But perhaps you say you *have* to write a program for it. Why? Will you be processing other similar files? That's a great reason to write a program. But now you have some other things to think about.

You mentioned lines 1-8 in BOOK1.txt. In the other similar files you need to process, will this always be exactly 8 lines? Or is there something about the lines themselves that tells you which ones to merge? The beginning of each line appears to have a `\something` code. Are these codes what you need to look at to decide exactly which lines to merge? Which line codes do you want to merge?

And what exactly does it mean to "merge" these lines? I notice that both BOOK1.txt and BOOK2.txt have a `\id BookName`, and it looks like those two lines should be combined into one. Is `BookName` a placeholder? Will the two input files have the same name here or two different names? What do you do in each case?

You probably get the idea by now. If you want to write a *program* to merge these files or other similar files, you need a detailed specification of exactly what this merging means and what it should do. Of course it doesn't have to have *every* detail just to get started, but you should have some idea about the questions I asked, and not just "lines 1-8". Until you have a start on that, you could throw code at the problem and never get it right.

Comment: I think that this is exactly what OP needed to hear. Thanks for taking the time to tell him that, +1

Comment: I have 5808 files for processing. That too 66 files each in 44 different languages (same language family). I have 2904 files with header information (line 1 to 8) with old text which I would like to replace with the text in another 2904 files with no header. This is the scenario. I know copy paste is not an easy solution for bulk file processing.

Comment: @JoshyKurian You last comment should have been part of the original question. But you still have a question that says "do my work for me" withiut you showng any effort in solving it yourself.

Comment: @Michael Geary - What I am looking is to merge two files. I need the lines starting from /id to /mt1 (the first 8 lines) from BOOK1.txt at the top and lines from /c 1 till the end of the file from BOOK2.txt afterwards merged into a file BOOK3.txt.

Comment: @Josh So is the procedure going to be to _always_ take the first 8 lines from file1, remove the first line of file2 (presumably checking to see that it matches the first line of file1), and insert the first 8 lines from file1 where the first line of file2 was? Or do you need to check those 8 lines to see if there is anything different about them? For example I see `toc1` and `toc2`. Could there also be a `toc3`? Or perhaps no `toc2` and only the `toc1`? If this happens will it still be 8 lines?

Comment: In either case you have some things to learn about: How do you read a file line by line in Python? Maybe  better, can you read the entire file and get all the lines in an array? If you read both files into arrays, how do you grab several elements out of one array and put those into the other array, replacing one of the elements in that array? If you can't count on it always being the first 8 lines from file1, how can you check the data in file1's array elements to see if it's what you expect? And at the end, how do you write an array back out to a text file?